# PHP - check if 24 hours have passed to let user make action

Tags: php, api, mysqli

I have a little API I'm building.

The user can "share" an object using the api, but I want to limit the user to share an object only once in 24 hours. for example, I have 5 objects. the user can share every object, but only after 24 hours, he can share the specific object again.

P.S: every object has an ID.

thanks

Comment: The simple solution is just to store when he last shared said object and check against the stored value, but without any knowledge of your use case, or data storage, or even objects, We can't give you an honestly helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a time() value when they start, then compare it to the current time() value every time its accessed. if the difference is greater than 60*60*24 then you know 24 hours has elapsed.

Comment: what about leapdays and leap seconds?

Comment: leap days are irrelevant and im pretty sure so are fractions of a second ;)

Comment: time() returns the unix time stamp (number of seconds since jan 1 1970) This value is uneffected by leap-anythings because you're dealing in seconds. You get the seconds passed when they start, and the seconds passed when you check (currently) and get the difference. The number left is the amount of seconds between start and now. YOu then do 60*60*24 to get the amount of seconds in a 24 hour period. If your value is greater, than its more than 24 hours.

Comment: yeah, but the API gives me a list of objects, and I want it to return also if the user can share this object or not...

Comment: Well I'm not really sure what the full context of the system is, but you can return a time stamp (time()) with each object (its creation time) and let the function using the api decide weather or not to let the new object be created. This is difficult to troubleshoot without context.

Comment: When you send the "create object request" to the api, the api should get the current timestamp, then check for a previously created object by that user. It should get the creation time of each object by the user and do the comparison I mentioned above. If it finds one within the timeframe of 24 hours it should send back a reply of "error" to the calling function.

Comment: If you are using sql, then you can use the where clause to only return objects from that user with a creation time of less than 24 hours ago in seconds as long as you are saving the creation timestamp in the unix time format. if any rows are returned then you throw an error.

Comment: and along with the error you can return the previously created objects if thats what you need it to do for your application.

Comment: OK, let me give you an example. I have 100 images, user can share any image only once in 24 hours. I want to disable the share button for 24 hours, till the next time he can share the specific image again.

Comment: Ok, so when the API returns the image to be shown, some sort of flag should also be sent back with the image indicating weather or not the image can be shared. Then on the receiving end you handle the UI to show the "share" button disabled or not based on the flag. To get the correct flag on the API side of things, do what I said above.

Comment: Essentially you'll have to timestamp every time the user shares something on the API side, so that it can figure out when or if that user is able to share that image again each time its fetched to show to the user.